# AdWhirl iAd rotation problem

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad, adwhirl

I integrated Adwhirl into my app and activated iAd only. My app is in landscapeleft mode and I want to have all Ads in 320x50(48) mode. I managed to rotate the banner view and the iAd looks right.I did this in the following way:

```
AdWhirl *adView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
[[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:adView];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 150);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 10, 10);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
[adView setTransform:transform];
```

It works fine in iOS4.2.
However,on device with iOS4.1,only left side of the banner view is clickable.I'm really confused about this behavior.Is there anyone having the same problem?
Any hint would be highly appreciated!

P.S.I tried to set frame,bounds,and center,but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: I've not used adwhirl before, but it sounds like you've got some other transparent object overlapping your iAds after rotation.  Also make sure that your adView you listed above has the autoresizesSubviews property set to YES before applying your transform.